# R, error replacement has xx rows, data has yy

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, replace, na

This seems to be basic one but I am not able to get how to solve this. I have a situation where I am writing a for loop where in at some stage it gives me this error, **"replacement has 3 rows, data has 4"**

In my for loop I am writing data for every 4 rows, and at some point the replacement data has only 3 values. I want that the 4th value should be filled with NA in this case. So basically length of 4 and if less say 2 then 2 values to be filled with NAs. How can I get this.

Example of the error message -

```
a1 <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = 4,ncol = 0))
v1 <- c(1:3)

a1[,"b1"] <- v1
```

So some code that converts v1 to length 4 and makes the last value as NA so that I am able to write it.

Comment: You can try to replace v1 in the last line with `ifelse(length(v1) < 4, c(v1, rep(NA, 4 - length(v1)), v1))`

Comment: `length(v1) <- nrow(a1); a1[,"b1"] <- v1`

Comment: @kath, thank you for answer, I believe there is a typo in the bracket, it should be `ifelse(length(v1) < 4, v1 <- c(v1,rep(NA, 4 - length(v1))), v1)` . Somehow it was not returning the 4 values with NA without **v1 <- **

Comment: @jogo, Thank you for your answer, however as I have mentioned, this is part of a forloop and hence nrow would keeping changing and would not meet the requirement as it is.

Comment: @user1412 Then you can do `length(v1) <- 4`

Comment: `a1$v1 <- v1[1:4]`

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to add (this works when `length(v1)==4` as well):

```
 v1 <- c(v1, rep(NA, nrow(a1) - length(v1)))
```

Comment: `length(v1) <- nrow(a1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
a1 <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = 4,ncol = 0))
v1 <- c(1:3)
v2 <- rep(NA, nrow(a1))
v2[1:length(v1)] <- v1
a1[,"b1"] <- v2
```

Comment: `v2 <- v1; length(v2) <- nrow(a1)`